# Can someone please give my stale pending edit some love?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, suggested-edits

Not sure why, but this [(months?-old) edit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/145364) is still awaiting review. A picture is worth a thousand words I hear. TIA.

Comment: Longest time between edit suggestion and approval: [posts](https://data.stackexchange.com/webapps/query/942645/longest-time-between-edit-suggestion-and-approval-only-posts?num=100), [tag-wikis](https://data.stackexchange.com/webapps/query/942650/longest-time-between-edit-suggestion-and-approval-only-tag-info?num=100) and [tag-wikis on meta](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.webapps/query/942650/longest-time-between-edit-suggestion-and-approval-only-tag-info?num=100).

Answer (score 4):

I've approved the edit now.

Thanks for bringing it to our attention